# JQuery Ajax MVC Partial View Not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am new to Asp.Net MVC and JQuery. I am trying to update my page with a partial view from my controller via JQUery and AJAX. But it does not seem to work I checked in Chrome Developer Tools and it seems to to make the call successfully it just never updates my page.

Here is my code:

Index Page:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
<section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>Nav</h1>

        </hgroup>
        <p>
           Click to show Nav
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
}

<div id="nav"></div>

@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".navLink").click(function (ev) {                
            ev.preventDefault();
            loadNav("/Home/_NavItems");
            return false;
        });

        function loadNav(url) {
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#div').html(data);

            });
        }




    });

    </script>
```

}

Like I said the information is coming through in developer tools so my function fires and my partial view is correct so I am just not sure if I might be missing something in my JQuery. But here is the code.

Partial View In controller:

```
 public PartialViewResult _NavItems()
    {
        List<NavItem> model = new List<NavItem>();
        model.Add(new NavItem(1, "asd", "asdas"));
        model.Add(new NavItem(2, "asd", "asdas"));
        model.Add(new NavItem(3, "asd", "asdas"));

        return PartialView(model);
    }


Actually View:

@model IEnumerable<PartialViewsTest2.Models.NavItem>



<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NameLast)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameLast)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Like I said I am very new to MVC and Jquery so if anything seems missing let me know please. My link is in the _layout file but like I said the requsest fires fine so the problem is not there. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: In `function loadNav(url) {` is `$('#div').html(data);` a typo? You dont appear to have an element with `id="div"`. Did you mean `$('#nav').html(data)`

Comment: :( Yes sir it was a mistake. Been on this for four hours trying new things and it was a wrongly named div, WOW. Thanks man. Its working now.  @StephenMuecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke is there anyway I can rep+ you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is updating an element with `id="div"`which does not appear to exist. You do have an element with `id="nav"` so change the function to

```
function loadNav(url) {
  $.get(url, function (data) {
    $('#nav').html(data);
  });
}
```